# Comparing bytes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, image-processing, binary

I have a binary blob header of either a JPG or MP4 file. I am trying to differentiate between the two.

When the file is a JPG, the first two bytes are `\xFF\xD8`. However, when I make the comparison `blob[0] == "\xFF"`, it fails. Even when I know that `blob[0]` IS in fact `\xFF`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Okay, so Ruby changes the ```"\xFF"``` to binary encoding only when printing. My solution was to use the force encoding method:

    ```"\xFF".force_encoding("BINARY") == blob[0]```

Comment: 0xff and 0xd8 are not bits, they're bytes and there is a significant difference between them. It'd be good to use the right terminology if you are developing code.

Comment: Did you try `blob[0] == '\xFF'.ord` or just `blob[0] == 0xFF`?

Comment: @mbratch: I think you mean `"\xFF".ord`, which is *identical* to `0xFF` and `255`.

Comment: @mbratch

`1.9.3p194 :003 > "\xD8".ord` yields

`ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`

Comment: @BrennanHolzer sorry about that. It wasn't clear what version of Ruby you were using in your question. The `"\xD8".ord` works in version 2.0. In version 1.9.3 just do `blob[0] == 0xFF`. It's more direct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an encoding issue. You are comparing a string with binary encoding (your JPEG blob) with a UTF-8 encoded string (`"\xFF"`):

```
foo = "\xFF".force_encoding("BINARY") # like your blob
bar = "\xFF"
p foo         # => "\xFF"
p bar         # => "\xFF"
p foo == bar  # => false
```

There are several ways to create a binary encoded string:

```
str = "\xFF\xD8".b                         # => "\xFF\xD8"  (Ruby 2.x)
str.encoding                               # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

str = "\xFF\xD8".force_encoding("BINARY")  # => "\xFF\xD8"
str.encoding                               # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

str = 0xFF.chr + 0xD8.chr                  # => "\xFF\xD8"
str.encoding                               # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

str = ["FFD8"].pack("H*")                  # => "\xFF\xD8"
str.encoding                               # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

All of the above can be compared with your blob.